# How to assign a calculation to function

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am trying to create a UDF to minimize the lines of data in a calculation. Rather than include the stated calculation of specific cell references, I want to create a variable called Rent_Rate and set it equal to Base_year_rent * ((1 + Rent_escalator)^Compound_period) so that the formula in the spread sheet reads "= Rent_Rate * Units (a static cell reference)"

I've tried defining the variables and setting each variable to the reference cell that I want (on a separate sheet) to reference.

```
Public Function Rent_Rate(Base_year_rent As Long, Rent_escalator As Long, Compound_period As Long, Rent_Rate As Long) As Long

    Base_year_rent = SH_Assumptions.Cells("C11")
    Rent_escalator = SH_Assumptions.Cells("C12")
    Compound_period = Year(Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Select) - Year(SH_Assumptions.Cells("C4"))

    Rent_Rate = Base_year_rent * ((1 + Rent_escalator) ^ Compound_period)

End Function
```

I expect that the output would be a specific value equal to the values entered into the cells being referenced.

Comment: Functions need parameters when used.  Thus, =Rent_Rate(year,escalator,compound)*Units.  Also, you can't have the function itself be a parameter in the function.

Comment: Debug >> Compile VBAProject. The `Rent_Rate` parameter can't have the same name as the function it's defined in, that's a duplicate declaration. Rename the parameter or the function.

Answer (score 1):

First off - a Function in Excel needs to have brackets, e.g. `=Rent_Rate()`

You *can* bypass that by setting up a Named Range with the name you want, which calls your UDF (e.g. a Named Range called `RentRate` which is `=Rent_Rate()`)

The next issue is that you have given your UDF 3 arguments, but aren't passing anything to them.  In fact, you are immediately overwriting them - just `Dim` the variables instead!

```vb
Public Function Rent_Rate() AS Long
    Dim Base_year_rent As Long, Rent_escalator As Long, Compound_period As Long, Rent_Rate As Long

    Base_year_rent = SH_Assumptions.Cells("C11").Value
    Rent_escalator = SH_Assumptions.Cells("C12").Value

    'What is this abomination supposed to do???
    Compound_period = Year(Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlUp)).Select) - Year(SH_Assumptions.Cells("C4"))

    Rent_Rate = Base_year_rent * ((1 + Rent_escalator) ^ Compound_period)

End Function
```

However, you still have a big problem here - **why are you using `ActiveCell` and `Select`?**  *Especially* in a UDF, you should [Avoid Using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  If you are trying to use the cell that is calling the function, look up `Application.Caller`

Comment: Does the `Rent_Rate = ...` instruction assign to the function's return value or to the `Rent_Rate` parameter? That's a "duplicate declaration in current scope" compile error.

Comment: Thanks to both for quick commentary. I'll try to answer them in order. For background. This is for a forecasting model calculating rental income by month for 3-5 year hold period. The Compound period is SUPPOSED to identify the Date (a column header), and extract the year, then subtract the year of the acquisition date (which resides on a separate sheet "Assumptions" in order to calculate the future Gross Rent on future periods.

Comment: I'm trying to get it to the point where the Rent_Rate = the value of those cells being multiple...in short I want to be able to use this is a function to simplify the length of a the longer formula (essentially running in the background) for ease of reading for some of my coworkers) who tend to get lost when the formula gets beyond 1 row. Sorry...This is the first thing I've tried to do in VBA...